# Does Colab run on randomly selected Google Cloud Platform regions?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was wondering if colab uses servers that are in random Google Cloud Platform regions. If so, would it be possible to select a preferred region? This would decrease data transfer costs from GCS to Colab.

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: it seems like colab uses random GCP regions at this time anywhere from US west to east, to UK and China.

Comment: It seems you can initialize, run `curl ipinfo.io` to see which server you've got assigned, and then terminate and repeat until you have region you are happy with.